# SQL Error Transport level

Tags: c#, sql-server, runtime-error

I get the following error at random intervals when executing my SQL Queries

```
Message: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has     occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0     - The specified network name is no longer available.)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean     breakConnection)'
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,     Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadBuffer()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`
```

I thought this might be due to a dropping network connection, is this correct?  How do I code around this?

Comment: *How do I code around this?* `_janitorService.PlugPowerCableBackIn();` Implementing this function is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I'd suggest upgrading your network kit, if this happens regularly.

Comment: I like the suggestion by @ta.speot.is but seriously there is no much that you can do. Usually this is one of exceptional conditions that an exception handler should handle.

Comment: The error comes when the application unable to connect to the sql server. You can increase ConnectionTimeout. That might help you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: but this keeps happening quite often, and our client is refusing to sign off on the project unless we resolve this.  I assume these are transient errors, should I put some retry logic, will it work?  Plus what do you mean by network kit?

Answer (score 1):

> I thought this might be due to a dropping network connection, is this correct?

Yes, "transport-level error" is a "geek talk" word for "network". This could also happen when the network connection becomes stale, for example, because your server gets rebooted after you obtain a connection and hold on to it for too long.

> How do I code around this?

Unfortunately, there is not much you can do about network connections. You can use `try`/`catch`, look for SQL exception, and retry with a retry count, but eventually you report this to your end users.

Comment: SQL TRY-CATCH does not catch transport-level errors.